# How can set value without link by Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I set value to GG Sheet by Script :

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetMeno=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheetMeno.getRange(1,1).setValue("cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg");
  sheetMeno.getRange(2,1).setValue("bg.ea.hb.hc.cb.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.cf.em");
```

But some cases , Text auto add link as image:

[image]

How can set value without link?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I want result of Cell(1,1) the same Cell(2,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, when `setShowHyperlink(false)` is used, `cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg` is put into a cell without the link. But, when you click the cell, the hyperlink is automatically set. Please be careful about this. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheetMeno.getRange(1,1).setValue("cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg");
```

#### To:

```
sheetMeno.getRange(1, 1).setValue("cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg").setShowHyperlink(false);
```

- When the cell is clicked and the cell has the link, please run `sheetMeno.getRange(1, 1).setShowHyperlink(false)`. By this, tbe link is removed.
- Or, how about the following modification?

  ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetMeno = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sheetMeno.getRange(1, 1).setValue("cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg");
    sheetMeno.getRange(2, 1).setValue("bg.ea.hb.hc.cb.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.cf.em");
    sheetMeno.getDataRange().setShowHyperlink(false);
  ```

#### Note:

- As another workaround, how about using the following sample script?

  ```
    const onSelectionChange = e => e.source.getDataRange().setShowHyperlink(false);
  ```

  - In this script, when the cell is selected, `onSelectionChange` is automatically run by the simple trigger. By this, when the cell is clicked and the hyperlink is automatically enabled, this script removes the hyperlink.
  - This is a simple sample script for testing the script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [setShowHyperlink(showHyperlink)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setShowHyperlink(Boolean))
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

### Added:

From your following additional request,

> Oh, Thank you, onSelectionChange remove all link in Document, Can only remove link in Cell or a Sheet (Ex Sheet1)?

How about the following sample script? In this sample script, the script is run on only "Sheet1".

```js
const onSelectionChange = e => {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  sheet.getDataRange().setShowHyperlink(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i had try setShowHyperlink(false);, It only not show link, but if you click in cell(1,1), it still exist link.

Comment: Can remove link in Cell(1,1)?

Comment: @D T Thank you for replying. About `but if you click in cell(1,1), it still exist link.`, I have already mentioned it in my answer. In the current stage, when the cell is clicked, it seems that the hyperlink is automatically set even when the link is removed. And, it seems that this cannot be turned off. I apologize for this situation. So, for example, when you confirmed that the cell has the link, as a current workaround, run the script of `sheetMeno.getDataRange().setShowHyperlink(false)`. And, how about reporting this to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)?

Comment: @D T When I tested this situation, for example, when the value is enclosed by the double quote like `setValue('"cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg"')` and as a 1st character, when `.`, `+` and `/` is added like `setValue(".cf.hb.cb.hc.bb.fa.aa.hd.ce.em.bg")`, `"+cf.hb` and `"/cf.hb`, it seems that the auto hyperlink is not run. And also, it seems that `#`, `$` can be used.

Comment: @D T I would like to try to look for whether another workaround can be found.

Comment: @D T As another workaround, I added a script for automatically running `setShowHyperlink`. Please confirm it. In the current stage, it seems that there is no direct method for disabling the auto-hyperlink on Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: I had try add [const onSelectionChange = e => e.source.getDataRange().setShowHyperlink(false);] , it not working.

Comment: @D T Thank you for replying. For example, when you reopen the Spreadsheet after you put the script and save the script, what result will you obtain? When this script is run, the hyperlinks are removed from all cell values of the data range.

Comment: I had add "onSelectionChange", but it still show underline of Link when click in cell.

Comment: @D T Thank you for repling. About `I had add "onSelectionChange", but it still show underline of Link when click in cell.`, when I tested this script, the hyperlinks are removed. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sorry,Must add trigger to run onSelectionChange ? Or Only copy to my  script?

Comment: @D T Now, I added a demonstration image to my answer. Please confirm it. About `Must add trigger to run onSelectionChange ?`, it's no. The function `onSelectionChange` is automatically run by the simple trigger. In this case, when a cell is selected, the script is automatically run as shown in my demonstration image. By the way, I cannot understand `Or Only copy to my script?`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: OK, Thank you, I had can try it, onSelectionChange  run very slow (about 5s).

Comment: @D T Thank you for replying. About `OK, Thank you, I had can try it, onSelectionChange run very slow.`, I apologize for this situation. Unfortunately, I cannot propose a clear method for resolving the speed in this simple script of a workaround. I apologize for this again. As shown my demonstration image, it is found that the processing time is not stable. It seems that this is the current specification at Google's side. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Oh, Thank you, onSelectionChange remove all link in Document, Can only remove link in Cell or a Sheet (Ex Sheet1)?

Comment: @D T About your additional request of `Oh, Thank you, onSelectionChange remove all link in Document, Can only remove link in Cell or a Sheet (Ex Sheet1)? `, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: OK. ありがとうございます, it is ok.